# find and fopen a file with random/unknown name with php

Tags: php, fopen, glob, opendir

I've searched around google for a way to fopen and read a file with an unknown/random name in a specific folder with a specific extension (it will be the only file in that folder, but it gets updated every hour with a new name), but couldn't find anything. Previously the file had the same name every time unfortunately now it changes...

previously i had to only define it  this way:

```
$file = "/var/uploads/quarter.csv";
$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
```

but with a random name it doesn't work anymore.

so, I've tried:

```
function the_file($dir = '/var/uploads/') {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.csv');
    $file = $files;
}

$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
```

script continues...

but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try listing the files in directory then some regular expression

Comment: glob returns an array, if you're certain that there's only 1 file in the folder then use `return $files[0];`.

Comment: how is it "not working"? any error messages? is var_dump($files) maybe helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$file` variable doesn't exist outside the function scope and hence you won't be able to use it outside the function. Also, [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) returns an array -- if there is only one file, you can just get the first element of the array and return it, like so:

```
function the_file($dir = '/var/uploads/') {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.csv');
    return $files[0]; // return the first filename
}
```

Now to store it in a variable, you can do:

```
$file = the_file(); // or specify a directory
# code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be:

If there is only one file in the directory, you can do a `scandir` to get the contents of the folder. (see [PHP ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).)

```
$dir    = 'your_folder_name';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
```

The content of the `$files` will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => yourfile.csv
)
```

So you can get the full name of the file with:

```
$filename = $files1[2];
```